# Matching Verts in 2 axis quickly

Tags: vertices, faces

I have deleted some faces and I wanted to create a new set of faces that run straight from some verts or lines. I have my side view here:

[image]

I have circled only 3 of the 10 verts thats I want to match up and then create faces using all my verts. Is there a way to get my verts to match up in the Z and Y axis but avoid the X axis quickly? Right now I work flow is this: Grab the vert to match > set cursor to selected > grab vert to move > scale vert in Z and Y to 0 > repeat x 10.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired result, though try S > Shift+X which will scale by all axes but X. Select all vertices to align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier then I was making it. Don't create a line in the back. Just take the front verts and extrude them. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of speed-ups worth learning for straightening, though:

After selecting 'Active Element' as your pivot point (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>)

To place a selection of vertices on straight line defined by 2 vertices:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the two vertices which define the line
- Create a new Transform Orientation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>). (It's worth checking 'Use after creation' and 'Overwrite Previous' if you do this a lot and don't want to accumulate lots of orientations.)
- Select the vertices you want to lie on the line. Usually they will be on a loop between your 2 defining vertices: if so, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click one of them to select all in between.
- With one of your line-defining vertices active, hit <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>(<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>),<kbd>0</kbd>

Likewise, to flatten a selection of vertices to a plane defined by 3 vertices

- Select the vertices which define the plane
- Create a new Transform Orientation
- Select the vertices you want to flatten, making sure one of your 3 is the active one at the end of selection.
- Hit <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>